# Question about James Munkres's "Analysis on Manifolds", p.112, Theorem 14.1

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lebesgue-measure

I'm an engineer who self-studies pure math in my free time, so I apologise in advance if this is a silly question. I am currently reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James Munkres. Theorem 14.1 states that "A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is rectifiable if and only if $S$ is bounded and Bd$S$ has measure zero". Here, Bd$S$ refers to the boundary of $S$, and is defined on p.29 as follows:

"Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The interior of $S$, as a subset of
$\mathbb R^n$, is defined to be the union of all open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ that are contained in $S$; it is denoted Int$S$. The exterior of $S$ is defined to be the union of all open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ that are disjoint from $S$; it is denoted Ext$S$. The boundary of $S$ consists of those points of $\mathbb R^n$ that belong neither to Int$S$ nor to Ext$S$ ; it is denoted Bd$S$."

Theorem 14.1 seems to me to imply that there can be subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where Bd$S$ does not have measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is what is confusing me. My intuition suggests that for any $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, Bd$S$ will be an $(n-1)$-manifold whose hyper-volume is zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, Bd$S$ will always have measure zero. Can anyone help me resolve this confusion? Do I need to have studied measure theory to fully understand this?

Comment: what means $BdS$ here?

Comment: Consider $S$ the set of irrational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. Its boundary is the whole $\mathbb{R}$. Now, if you consider $S$ to be an m-dimensional submanifold, then I think your intuition is correct, the boundary would be some $m-1$ dimensional submanifold.

Comment: The notation Bd$S$ and the "boundary" terminology have several meanings in mathematics, depending on the context. It is very important to know the exact definition that Munkres is using in that context you quote. You should include that definition in your thoughts about this issue (as well as editing your post to put it in explicitly).

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for pointing this out, as I was unaware of the ambiguity.

Comment: @Masacroso I have edited the post with the definition. It is the boundary of $S$.

Comment: That is still not a definition. It's just using terminology instead of notation. As I said in my comment, that terminology/notation has several definitions, and you need to put in the definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher Okay, apologies. I've added the definition in.

Comment: Actually, there are open subsets of the real line, whose boundary has positive measure. Similarly, there are Jourdan curves in the plane which have positive measure, they are called Osgood curves. Yes, all this is a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: Keep reading the book. Example 1 in Section 14 gives the  construction of an open set where the boundary has nonzero measure.

Comment: @RRL Thanks. I clearly got stuck on this, and that prevented me from reading on, haha.